# How to get a date in a specified format in Google Sheets App script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a function to compare a date in a cell of a column to today's date and create a column for today if it is missing.

```js
function isColumn() {
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+1', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
 ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  s = ss.getSheetByName("Register")
  var dateCell = s.getRange(2,3,1,1)
  Logger.log(dateCell.setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").getValue())
  Logger.log(today.valueOf())
  if (dateCell.getValue().valueOf() === today.valueOf()) {
  Logger.log("Today's column exists")
  } else {
  Logger.log("Create today's column")

  }
}
```

This is the log I always get

```js
4:43:23 PM  Info    Thu Nov 11 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2021
4:43:23 PM  Info    11.11.2021
4:43:23 PM  Info    Create today's column
```

The if condition can never evaluate as the date formats are wrong even though I used .setNumberFormat() method and the date displays in the correct format in the sheet.

How can I make the .getValue() method get the date in the correct format so I can evaluate the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDisplayValue()` instead.

> getDisplayValue() Returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range. The
> value is a String. The displayed value takes into account date, time
> and currency formatting formatting, including formats applied
> automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting. Empty cells return
> an empty string.

**Example:**

```
function isColumn() {
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+1', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
 ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  s = ss.getSheetByName("Register")
  var dateCell = s.getRange(2,3,1,1);
  dateCell.setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
  Logger.log(dateCell.getDisplayValue());
  Logger.log(today.valueOf())
  if (dateCell.getValue().valueOf() === today.valueOf()) {
  Logger.log("Today's column exists")
  } else {
  Logger.log("Create today's column")
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: @noquestiontoosilly - If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution too, meanwhile.

```js
function isColumn() {
  var today = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('cs-CZ')
 ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  s = ss.getSheetByName("Register")
  var dateCell = s.getRange(2,3,1,1).setNumberFormat("dd.mm.yyyy")
  if (dateCell.getValue() === "") {
  Logger.log("Create today's column")
  createColumn()
  }else{
    Logger.log(dateCell.getValue().toLocaleDateString ('cs-CZ'))
  }
  
  Logger.log(today)
  if (dateCell.getValue().toLocaleDateString('cs-CZ') === today) {
  Logger.log("Today's column exists")
  } else {
  Logger.log("Create today's column")
  createColumn()
  
  }
}
```

Converting the dates to locale date strings also worked for making it possible to evaluate the if condition.

Notice how I avoided `Utilities` all together to prevent date incompatibilities.